# Error al importar android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy tratando de realizar la siguiente aplicación [Google Map Place](https://www.kodetr.com/membuat-place-autocomplete-menggunakan-google-map-berbasis-android/) pero tengo problemas con la siguiente importacion **import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity**  el proyecto no me la reconoce
[image: android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity]
Cuando agrego la implementation al gradle me dice que no es compatible

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si esa es la librería correcta o tendria que implemetar otra

Comment: implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'

Comment: Usa la secuencia de teclas Alt+Enter para que muestre la sección correcta,revisa mi respuesta, saludos.

Comment: si me quito el error del gradle pero sigue sin importarme en la clase main import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

Answer (score 0):

El problema es la definición incorrecta de la dependencia.

La dependencia no es soportada debido a la configuración de tu build.gradle, coloca el puntero del mouse y mediante la secuencia de teclas <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> se abrirá un menú contextual, sugiriendo la adecuada versión, reemplazala con la indicada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si me quito el error del gradle pero sigue sin importarme en la clase main import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

Comment: Ese es otro detalle, elimina el import de FragmentActivity y da Alt+Enter sobre la palabra FragmentActivity de tu clase para agregar el import

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer hubo una migración
ya no uses:
import android.support.v4.app.
sino:
import androidx.fragment.app.*